# It's ok testing mediation in lavaan using ML estimator and Yuan- Bentler correction to get bootstrap CI?

Tags: mediation, lavaan

I'm testing mediation with a SEM of four exogenous variables with three mediators on latent variable. I have non-normal variables, so I used MLR estimator for the adjusment, but I can't get the bootstrap CI with this estimator.

I found in a google forum that MLR uses yuan-bentler correction. I can add the test=yuan.bentler.mplus code to a ML estimator fit calculation, adding boostrap and getting the CI. I got the robust indexes values and the CI. However I don't know if this is a right procedure. Should I report the use of ML and Yuan Bentler correction in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the post you found already explained that there are 2 different robust corrections: one for the *SE*s (which therefore makes the Wald (*z) tests robust) and another for the likelihood-ratio test (LRT: $\chi^2$ test of the $H_0$ that your model captures all features of the data-generating process).  If you look at the `estimator=` description on the `?lavOptions` help page, you can confirm that `estimator = "MLR"` is a shortcut that sets both robust options:

```
estimator = "ML"
se = "robust.huber.white"
test = "yuan.bentler.mplus"
```

And you can read which robust `estimator=` options set which other values for `se=` and `test=`.  As you discovered, you can explicitly set either option to `"boot"` or `"bootstrap"` to use that option.  There is nothing wrong with using bootstrap for *SE*s and CIs, but using the Yuan-Bentler correction for the model-fit test statistic.  However, if you request robust *SE*s, then you can still use the much more efficient parametric bootstrap; see the `semTools::monteCarloCI()` help page, and the reference therein to read about its advantages.

Also, if you have complete data, then it is better to use the Satorra-Bentler correction instead (`estimator = "MLM"`, or just `test = "Satorra.Bentler"` if you still want `se = "boot"`).  It is more efficient and maintains Type I error rates better at smaller sample sizes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, is there a reference that you could give for cite the rational to choose MLM in a research paper? Grettings